# How to get the return value of a script called with su

Tags: android, bash, shell, exit-code, su

I want to call a script `stuff.sh` with the superuser rights and then get its exit code. However doing something like `su -c ./stuff.sh; echo $?` always prints 0. I assume that's because the return value contained in `$?` refers to the `su` return value and not to `stuff.sh` one.

How can I retrieve the correct value of my script `stuff.sh`?

**Edit 1** When I'm doing `su -c './stuff.sh; echo $?'`, `echo` returns the correct value of `stuff.sh` exit code, but I cannot get it out of the `su` by doing something like `su -c './stuff.sh; eval echo $? $code'` : `echo $code` returns 0 as soon as I'm leaving the `su` command.

**EDIT 2** I should have mentioned the context and my distribution because indeed this is not a problem on Ubuntu.
`su -c stuff.sh` is called from another script `call.sh`, which is itself executed as a process by an Android application.

Comment: Can you put in quotes like `su -c './stuff.sh; echo $'?`

Comment: That's simply that, thank you so much! Can't believe I didn't think of doing that earlier.

Comment: Check the `EXIT VALUES` section of `man su`. It's pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is, `su` is supposed to return the exit status of the command it executed according to the man, but in my case, it didn't. I always had 0 as an exit value whereas my script was supposed to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Per the man page

```
su normally returns the exit status of the command it executed.  If the command was killed by a signal, su returns the number of the
   signal plus 128.

   Exit status generated by su itself:

             1      Generic error before executing the requested command

             126    The requested command could not be executed

             127    The requested command could was not found
```

If this is an option, use ssh to get your return code

```
ssh -l username localhost "command" 
echo $?
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange. Exit codes can be reachable for me after running su:

```
$ su -c true ; echo $? 
0
$ su -c false ; echo $?                                
1
```

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: My script is called on Android from a Java application. And I have the same result as you (normal behaviour) when I'm running those lines on terminal on Ubuntu.

Comment: Uhh. Then mention this environment in the original question. It looks like the POSIX implementing is not so perfect.

Comment: Yes I've just changed it, I realized that was fundamental in this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some quotes allows to get the actual exit code of `stuff.sh`. The correct syntax is:

`su -c './stuff.sh; echo $?'`