# Jenkins docker pipeline not passing exit codes

Tags: docker, jenkins

we had some issues with jenkins docker stages, where they needed to be run with root permissions (args root:root). At this time, I'm not 100% recalling why they made this decision, but I couldn't get around it a few months ago.

The issue we mainly ran into with root:root was that jenkins couldn't clean up after itself, as the docker filesystem was owned by root user.

So, I created created some mascarade commands in my global groovy library

```
def container_init (myUserId) {
    sh( returnStdout: true, script: """/usr/sbin/useradd -u ${myUserId} dummy;""").trim()
}
def command (input) {
    sh( returnStdout: true, script: """su dummy -c '${input}';""").trim()
}
```

The problem now is that some of these docker_mask.command() are not passing exit code from failed e2e tests or even failed terraform deployments. Some are passing and positively exciting, but it's inconsistent.

Anything I can do to get positive exits?

Answer (score 2):

## tldr

the exit code youre wanting/expecting is getting swallowed by the `su` command.

## long version

Basically, your exit code will always be `0` because you were successfully able to switch to the `dummy` user.

the "quick and dirty" way around this problem is to do something like

```bash
su dummy -c '${input}; exit $?'
```

which should bubble up the exit code you were expecting.

### relavent:

- [How to get the return value of a script called with su](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40845705/4526019)

**caveat:**

I'm assuming you're attempting to work around some of the challenges described here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/pull/57

My unsolicited $0.02 is there are many pitfalls/"footguns" around this approach and adding the shenanigans that Jenkins and Docker introduce doesn't help. Relying on just the exit codes will be unpredictable, hard to debug, or nearly impossible to cancel jobs cleanly (at least in my experience ) so plz be cautious with whatever solution you find.

Comment: Thanks, my team spotted something like this yesterday; cool cool. Wondering if non-last commands will exit, or if this will just identify the presence of an exit 1

Comment: I think that depends on a few things. when run as a command rather than a script, you only ever get the status of the last command. with a script you have the option of setting the 'pipefail' option but that can still cause probs w/ tools like terraform https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform/issues/152 or other random things like printing out version of a tool https://github.com/deric4/github-action-runner-reference/actions/runs/3604148881/attempts/1#summary-9853585725